# EC2 autoscaling taking too long to scale out for target tracking policy

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

Have configured an autoscaling group attached to a load balancer. It uses a target tracking autoscaling policy with load balancer request count per target as the metric. I have updated the warmup period to 30s and cooldown to 10s from their default values. Despite doing these changes, the instances are scaling out only after 5mins have passed and they're handling traffic after another 5mins. This results in a total of 10mins for the scaling action to take place. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix this